# Trust Internal CA on WES7

Tags: certificate-authority, thin-client, windows-embedded

We have set up an RDS farm with a certificate issued by our internal Enterprise CA. I'm trying to connect some Wyse thin clients to it running WES7, however it reports a certificate error as the thin clients do not trust the CA.

How can I get these WES7 thin clients to trust our internal CA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the root certificate (and any intermediate certificates) on each thin client. This should be done automatically by default for clients that are joined to the domain. If they are not domain joined, you'll have to configure some other delivery mechanism for the CA's root cert.

Comment: Thanks - they're not domain joined, it's that "other delivery mechanism" that I'm looking for. Any suggestions?

Comment: Incidentally how do you domain join a WES7 thin client?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb521355(v=WinEmbedded.51).aspx

Comment: And you can script it, deliver it via SCCM or other Config Management tool, do it by hand, etc.

Comment: Ah, I see. The problem is I'm using a couple of locked down Wyse loan units. So doesn't look like this is going to work.